# create a sign up / register form modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im not quite good at jquery so i was using this two plugins for my development. I'm currently using a php file. the problem is that i can't code it on jquery.

http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

I was trying to create a modal popup of register and sign in using modal popup with this code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="modal-login-register">Register/Login</a>

    <div class="register">
        <h1>this modal is for register</h1>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[user-registration]')?>
        <a href="#" class="login">Login Instead</a>
    </div>

    <div class="login">
        <h1>this modal is for login</h1>
        <a href="#" class="register">register Instead</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

I was trying with sweet alert but can't figure to work it out. 
https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Here's the code of my test code in jquery.

```
$('.link-modal').on('click', function () {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Title',
        content: 'url:test2.php',
        onContentReady: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.setContentPrepend('<div>Prepended text</div>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.setContentAppend('<div>Appended text after 2 seconds</div>');
            }, 2000);
        },
        columnClass: 'medium',
    });
  });
```

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: it looks like you are using bootstrap . are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: Hello @shubham715 no im not using bootstrap as the grid have a customized codes in css

Comment: you dont need to use sweetalert for this, check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp